# My laptop is not been able to boot

Tags: dual-boot

Just yesterday I was working on windows 7 in my laptop (which is even having Ubuntu 14.04).
After that I selected to restart the laptop to continue my work from ubuntu,
but after the restart happen, GRUB boot loader is not shown and only the laptop logo is seen several times.
what do i have to do to get it repaired without erasing the storage part?

Comment: You can backup storage using Ubuntu install usb and by using "Try Ubuntu without Installing" option I guess. You can check the efi partition and configuration files in it just to make sure it's not a grub problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem .
the solution is boot-repair.
download the iso from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) and then make a bootable usb (you can use UNetbootin to make it).
boot your laptop on it than choose "Recommended Repair".
it will automatically reinstall Grub and repair your laptop without erasing the storage part.
you can see this link for more informations:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: will it work on both OS, I meant to say that it should show the option for either to start windows or Ubuntu

Comment: can't I repair that with Ubuntu liveCD?

Comment: boot-repair will simply reinstall the grub on the Ubuntu partition you it will show  the option either to start windows or Ubuntu

Comment: you can use Ubuntu liveCD and install boot-repair on it after  booting.this option is explained here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair     it is the same

Comment: yes it is the same